# Tetenal Colortec C-41 developing kit appears to be out of stock everywhere in the UK. Suggestions?

Tags: film, developing, processing

As the title suggests, the popular Tetenal Colortec C-41 developing kit appears to be out of stock everywhere in the UK... Does anybody know if there is an issue with supply, or whether there are other reputable kits to purchase online?

It's my first adventure into colour, so being able to follow what others have done on Youtube with the same kit would be useful, but I'm not tied down to that.

Open to learning :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tetenal filed for bankruptcy in October 2018 and was closed down by April 1st 2019.

Some of the employees have taken over the company and intend to continue production and sale under the name 'New Tetenal'. The [new web shop](https://shop.new-tetenal.de/) is open for pre-orders, but they have not yet made any statements on when they are intending to deliver.

C-41 developer kits for home use are also manufactured by at least Fuji, Compard, Rollei and Cinestill, but availability from these manufacturers has also been unreliable and I am not sure which products are available in the UK.